# Basic box drawing not showing up

Tags: c, ncurses

I'm trying to use ncurses to draw some boxes for now. Unfortunately, nothing is showing up.

I'm pretty sure it's something basic. The code is quite short.

```
#include <curses.h>

void create_win(int height, int width, int y, int x);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    int size = 10;

    initscr();
    clear();
    noecho();
    cbreak();

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        create_win(size, size, size + i, size + i);
    }

    getch();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}

void create_win(int height, int width, int y, int x)
{
    WINDOW *win;

    win = newwin(height, width, y, x);
    box(win, 0, 0);

    wrefresh(win);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wgetch(win) instead of getch()  getch() is not compatible with the win stuff.